# Font not rendering?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, font-face

I have the following CSS (generated byn SASS):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "locust";
  src: url(/assets/LOCUST.TTF) format("truetype");
  src: url(/assets/LOCUST.svg) format("svg"); }
```

The path seems accessible - I'm on `localhost:3000` and if I can download/see the fonts by typing `localhost:3000/assets/LOCUST.TTF`, for instance.

Yet Firefox don't render the font:

```
<h1 style="font-family: locust;">Test</h1>
```

I'm using Rails, but I don't think the problem is related, since the HTML and CSS generated seems correct to me, and the fonts are accessible. If I knew what I need to generate, most likely I would know how to fix.

Comment: Try get a WOFF font for FF. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face

Answer (score 0):

**Asset URL**

Here is code we use:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/fonts.css.scss
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    src: asset_url('layout/fonts/lato/lato-hairline-webfont.eot');
    src: asset_url('layout/fonts/lato/lato-hairline-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         asset_url('layout/fonts/lato/lato-hairline-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         asset_url('layout/fonts/lato/lato-hairline-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         asset_url('layout/fonts/lato/lato-hairline-webfont.svg#latohairline') format('svg');
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Notice `asset_url` is used -- this provides a CSS-compatible path to the url (hence why you're not able to access the path)

---

**WebFonts**

If you have full rights to use the font, you'd be better using the WebFont generator here: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

This creates cross-browser webfont files in `.tff`, `.woff`, `.svg` and `.eot` formats